# Close off-topic questions that contain a bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I've come across a bountied question that looks pretty off-topic to me, [My iptables is being automatically modified to drop all output packets. How to debug it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61849810/my-iptables-is-being-automatically-modified-to-drop-all-output-packets-how-to-d), and according to a [question on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-can-we-close-questions-with-bounties), I've flagged it for the attention of a moderator. My flag has been declined with the following message:

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

What's the proper way of dealing with this? As declining flags leads to a review ban, I'd like to know whether it was wrong to flag this question in the first place

Comment: Declined flags do not lead to review suspension. A high number of recent declined flags can lead to _flag_ suspension.

Comment: @yivi thanks for clarifying that! Nevertheless, how should that be handled? Flagging stuff that needs a flag IMO should not lead to a ban, should it?

Comment: Mods will act in egregious cases, where no domain expertise is needed. If a case is not completely clear cut, the mod can opt for prudence and decline the flag. You even recommended the user to post their question in SF, which is a sister site which a lot of overlap with SO. (Not even sure if it should be asked there, or probably better at askubuntu or SU).

Comment: @yivi I've recommended that in a comment to the post itself

Comment: Yes, you recommended server fault. My point exactly. Making the judgement about _where_ that question belongs may not be absolutely black and white. Personally, I believe SF is the wrong recommendation. And there are a lot of questions about [iptables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iptables) here on SO as well... Do I like the question? No. Would I have raised the flag? Neither.

Comment: As the tag wiki states in uppercase letters: "GENERAL IPTABLES SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC", so flagging that question does not look wrong to me. But you're right, I might have been wrong about where it should have been posted instead

Comment: What I mean simply is that with flags like this one is asking a mod to make a judgement call. If the call is not 100% clear, the judgement can go either way. I try to raise these "remove bounty" flags only when I think there is no room for doubt in the outcome. And even then, the mod can of course disagree. It happens.

Comment: The bounty on that question expires in four hours. I'd say the simplest option is to just *wait*, and VTC as soon as the bounty expires.

Comment: I agree with @F1Krazy. Under normal circumstances, I'd cancel the bounty and close the question. But for bounties that expire in less than 12-24 hours, I'm inclined to just wait it out, and then come back to close the question. (The only way that mods can cancel a bounty is by refunding the reputation. There's no way we can avoid refunding it.)

Comment: @CodyGray Bounty is going to get refunded when it gets deleted anyway.

Comment: Dang, good point, @psubsee2003...

Comment: And the question's been punted to Ask Ubuntu; hopefully it'll get a  better reception there.  As as power user/admin question it looks plausible; but I don't have the domain knowledge to evaluate directly.

Comment: That’s exactly what I thought, @Dan. :-)

Answer (score 6):

In your flag message, you did not mention that the question has an active bounty:

> This question should be closed, as it is not related to programming

If a bounty needs to be removed, please state that as the main reason in your custom flag.

Otherwise custom flags requesting question closure will be declined as custom flags are not meant to be used for this purpose.

Comment: Good point - I haven't thought about the situation that the mod doesn't see that there is an active bounty

Comment: @NicoHaase it is best to assume the mod has no context at all. The onus is on you to explain to the mod why you or any other regular user can't do what you ask the mod to do on your behalf. Feel free to join the SOCVR chat room if you want a second opinion or guidance on how best to word your custom flag.